# Azure pipeline doesn't allow to enable pull request validation

Tags: github, azure-pipelines

While trying to enable Azure pull request validation it throws following error.

```
Unable to configure a service on the selected GitHub repository. This is likely caused by not having the necessary permission to manage hooks for the selected repository.
```

I have created a github connection with access token. And enabled all the scopes as follows, What exact scope do I need to enable?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the scopes are not the main cause of your issue. I generated different github PATs and found the pipeline with `Azure pull request validation` enabled can work well even when I only defined part of what you've defined above.

Please check this [similar issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/469896/github-service-connection-not-working.html), check if you can directly create a webhooks in Github web UI. (Github=>Settings=>Webhooks). And according to [reply from Eddie](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/solutions/202469/view.html):

*If it is a personal repository, only the repository owner can create hooks. If it is an organization repository, you need at least "Admin permissions" which can "Change a repository's settings" with "Adding, removing, and editing webhooks and service hooks permission included.*

Hope it helps.

Comment: you're correct. In my case, only the owner can create hooks.